# scala generic conversion A[T] => B[T]

Tags: scala, generics, type-bounds

I am trying to use generics to not lose the subtype of the implementation.
It's not totally clear to me how to search for this question although I believe it has as a name.
I've a trait named conf and some implementations (where WB is an instance of Params):

```
trait Conf[P <: Params]

class ConfInstance extends Conf[WB]
```

now I want that a backend can convert this type parameters into a different class like this:

```
trait Coder[P <: Params]
class AABBCC(conf: Conf[WB]) extends Coder[WB]

def backend[P <: Params](conf: Conf[P]): Coder[P] = {
    conf match {
        case abcConf: ConfInstance => new AABBCC(abcConf)
    }
```

but the compiler complains with : "Expression of type AABBCC" doesn't conform to expected type Coder[P]"

What I tryed was to add an asInstanceOf[Coder[P]] but I don't like this solution.

So which is the correct way to do this conversion?

Comment: compiles fine for me (if I add `trait Params` and `trait WB extends Params`). How do you define them?

Comment: Turned out  intellij reported a non error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be IDE issue (is it IntelliJ IDEA?).

IDE incorrectly reports about compile error but the code compiles.

[image]

.

Comment: Yep you are right, I just stopped when intellij show the error and was stuck trying to clear it. But looks like that when I compile it does not complain. Weird, first time I see intellij do wrong

Comment: It does not compile for me, and I don't think it should.

Comment: Hmm ... yeah, looks like you are correct. I did something wrong when I tried it myself. I am really surprised to see it, but it does indeed work ... very strange. 
If you "edit" your answer, I would then be able to retract my downvote.

Comment: @Dima "Edited".

Comment: "Weird, first time I see intellij do wrong" – There's probably at least about one question per month on [so] that turns out to be a bug in the IntelliJ semantic analyzer.